# r - data.table set add number to certain j values only

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table named chance where I am attempting to add 32 to each value that is less than 100.

```
chance <- data.table(Fe = c(75, 50, 100, 60, 60, 50, 60, 100))

> chance
    Fe
1:  75
2:  50
3: 100
4:  60
5:  60
6:  50
7:  60
8: 100
```

The following code is my attempt to change certain rows in j where i is true:

```
# changing Fe
change <- "Fe"
for (col in change) set(chance, i = which(chance[[col]] < 100), j = col,
value = chance[[col]] + 32L) # Source 3
```

This is the resulting error:

```
# Warning message:
# In set(chance, i = which(chance[[col]] < 100), j = col, value =
# chance[[col]] +  :
# Supplied 8 items to be assigned to 6 items of column 'Fe' (2 unused)
```

This is the result that I want:

```
> chance
    Fe
1:  107
2:  82
3: 100
4:  92
5:  92
6:  82
7:  92
8: 100
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `:=` to update by reference as follows:

```
chance[Fe < 100L, Fe := Fe+32L]
```

Or you might have many columns that you would like to update, you can use `set` as follows:

```
for (col in myCols) {
    idx <- which(chance[[col]] < 100L)
    set(chance, i=idx, j=col, value=chance[[col]][idx] + 32L)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(data.table)
chance <- data.table(Fe = c(75, 50, 100, 60, 60, 50, 60, 100))
chance$Fe[chance$Fe < 100] = chance$Fe[chance$Fe < 100]+32

#or (using ifelse function)
chance <- data.table(Fe = c(75, 50, 100, 60, 60, 50, 60, 100))
chance$Fe <- ifelse(chance$Fe < 100, chance$Fe+32, chance$Fe)

#or ( using data.table way)
chance <- data.table(Fe = c(75, 50, 100, 60, 60, 50, 60, 100))
chance[Fe<100, Fe:=Fe+32]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `case_when()` function is perfect for this.

```
library(dplyr)
chance <- data.table(Fe = c(75, 50, 100, 60, 60, 50, 60, 100)) %>%
  mutate(
    Fe_new = case_when(
    Fe < 100 ~ Fe + 32,
    TRUE ~ Fe)
    )
```